# Custom Alert works only once

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created custom alert with Modal in react native but it renders only once.
This is my component

```
import {Text, View, Modal, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {styles} from '../../Styles';

const CustomAlert = props => {
  const {title, msg, visible} = props;
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(visible);
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={alert}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.centeredView}
          onPress={() => {
            // setAlert(false);
          }}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text>{title}</Text>
            <Text>{msg}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => setAlert(false)}>
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>OK</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This is how I'm rendering it my screen

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
const submit = () => {
    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;
    if (!name) {
      setAlert(true);
      return;
    }}
```

And in return on Screen

`{alert && <CustomAlert title="asdasd" msg="asd23" visible={alert} />}`

And in m Screen when i click on button to render this alert it only works once , i have logged props whis also show once

**EDIT**
@Thinker's answer works but How to render this customAlert component from action? If an action or api call completes, how to render this component and show message in any screen as actions in redux does not allow to render compponent there because they are not react functional components....

Comment: Once the alert is shown, how do you hide it? or it does not hide?

Comment: you have to update the `alert` value to `false` once the modal is closed, so that the `setAlert(true)` will trigger again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setAlert(true)` will not trigger/update the `alert` value because it's already `true` when it got triggered once. (Because `useState` will not update the same variable value again)

You can achieve your goal by changing the `alert` by triggering the `setAlert` in the `onPress` of `CustomModal` directly. Something like this (I haven't run it, but my logic is as below):

This will be your **main component**:

```js
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MainComponent = () => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);

  const submit = () => {
    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;
    if (!name) {
      setAlert(true);
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {' '}
      {alert && (
        <CustomAlert
          title="asdasd"
          msg="asd23"
          visible={alert}
          onPress={(value) => setAlert(value)}
        />
      )}{' '}
    </View>
  );
};
```

This is the **CustomAlert**:

```js
import {Text, View, Modal, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {styles} from '../../Styles';

const CustomAlert = props => {
  const {title, msg, visible, onPress} = props;

  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={alert}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.centeredView}
          onPress={() => {
            // setAlert(false);
          }}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text>{title}</Text>
            <Text>{msg}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => onPress(false)}>
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>OK</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: this works. but i have updated question can to take a look at it.